# show rating alert when deleting app in iphone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uialertview, rating

I have seen in most of the apps which i install using itunes has shows a alert please rate the app when deleting the app? is it by default behaviour or we can create it programmatically in our app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is the default system behaviour.

Comment: but in our native app this alert doesn't appears.I think apple does it when we submit app to app store

Comment: right, it doesn't happen for AdHoc builds you install yourself, only for apps from the store.

Comment: How could you rate an app which isn't on the app store anyway? ;)